# Merge edge sequences from 2 different graphs as one graph, R

Tags: r, igraph

I created 2 graphs. I found there are common nodes between these 2 graphs. I want to merge the common nodes in both the graphs as one graph. I got the edge sequence of nodes (common) from graph 1, similarly I extracted edge sequences of the same nodes from graph 2. How do I merge the edge sequences from these 2 graphs as one graph?

```
    idx <- match(c("DISC1","GSK3B", "YWHAE", "NRG1", "BDNF", "FYN", "DCC", "FOXP2", "GRM5", "MIR137", "NEUROG1"), V(prenatal_direct)$name)# common nodes in graph 1

    g <-E(prenatal_direct) [ from(idx) ] # edge sequence of common nodes in graph 1



+ 71/139 edges from e0b7f5c (vertex names):
 [1] AKT1  --DISC1    BDNF  --ARNT2    BDNF  --HAP1     BDNF  --HTT     
 [5] BDNF  --NPAS4    DCC   --DSCAM    DCC   --FAK      DCC   --FYN     
 [9] DCC   --MADD2    DCC   --NTN1     DCC   --STX1A    DCC   --TUBB3   
[13] DCC   --VAMP7    DISC1 --DTNBP1   DISC1 --GSK3B    DISC1 --YWHAE   
[17] DISC1 --ACTB     DISC1 --ADCYAP1  DISC1 --CHL1     DISC1 --DIXDC1  
[21] DISC1 --ERBB4    DISC1 --EXOC1    DISC1 --FEZ1     DISC1 --GRB2    
[25] DISC1 --ITPR1    DISC1 --ITPR3    DISC1 --KIF5A    DISC1 --NDE1    
[29] DISC1 --NDEL1    DISC1 --NKX2-2   DISC1 --PAFAH1B1 DISC1 --PDE4B   
[33] DISC1 --SRR      DISC1 --TNIK     DISC1 --ZNF365   DISC1 --ZNF385A 
[37] DLG2  --FYN      FOXP2 --MEF2C    FOXP2 --MIR132   FOXP2 --MIR9    
+ ... omitted several edges

    idx_indirect <-match(c("DISC1","GSK3B", "YWHAE", "NRG1", "BDNF", "FYN", "DCC", "FOXP2", "GRM5", "MIR137", "NEUROG1"), V(prenatal_indirect)$name)# common nodes in graph 2

    g_indirect <- E(prenatal_indirect) [ from(idx_indirect) ] # edge sequence of common nodes in graph 2

+ 78/216 edges from ebb1a90 (vertex names):
 [1] BDNF --GSK3B    BDNF --MIR137   BDNF --NOS1     BDNF --NRG1     BDNF --CREB1   
 [6] BDNF --EGF      BDNF --EGR3     BDNF --EPS8     BDNF --ERK1     BDNF --ERK2    
[11] BDNF --MECP2    BDNF --MIR9     BDNF --NAB2     BDNF --NGFR     BDNF --NTRK2   
[16] BDNF --TH       BDNF --WASF1    DCC  --BCL11A   DCC  --FYN      DCC  --NTN1    
[21] DCC  --RASA1    DCC  --TRIO     DISC1--GSK3B    DISC1--NRXN1    DISC1--PCM1    
[26] DISC1--APP      DISC1--ATF4     DISC1--BBS4     DISC1--CCDC141  DISC1--DAAM1   
[31] DISC1--DAB1     DISC1--DIXDC1   DISC1--ERK1     DISC1--FOXD3    DISC1--GABRB2  
[36] DISC1--GABRB3   DISC1--KALRN    DISC1--KIF5C    DISC1--LRRC7    DISC1--MEK     
[41] DISC1--MYH2     DISC1--NDEL1    DISC1--OLIG2    DISC1--PAFAH1B1 DISC1--PDE4B   
[46] DISC1--PDE4D    DISC1--RASSF7   DISC1--RHOA     DISC1--SMO      DISC1--SOX10   
+ ... omitted several edges
```

Thanks

Priya

Comment: @G5W To give an idea, of how common nodes in 2 different graphs have different edge sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created two sub graphs using the edge sequence for selected nodes and then merged the two sub graphs.

Example:Graph 1 and Graph 2 has 10 nodes, I am interested in merging A, B,C,D and E nodes from graph 1 and graph 2

```
idx <- match(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), V(graph 1)$name)# selected nodes in graph 1 

g <-E(graph 1) [ from(idx) ] # edge sequence of selected nodes in graph 1

idx_indirect <-match(c("A", "B", "C", "D". "E"), V(graph 2)$name)# selected nodes in graph 2

g2 <- E(graph 2) [ from(idx_indirect) ] # edge sequence of selected nodes in graph 2

g_subgraph <- subgraph.edges(graph 1, g)# create sub graph for edge sequence in graph 1
g2_subgraph <- subgraph.edges(graph 2, g2)# create sub graph for edge sequence in graph 2

graph= graph.union(g_subgraph,g2_subgraph, byname = T) # merge both sub graphs
```

Priya

Answer (score 2):

You can find the list of shared nodes, then get all edges from either graph that contains one of these nodes. I illustrate with some artificial data.

### Initial Data

```
EL1 = structure(c("ZUNO", "IPHL", "ESZF", "IPHL", "IPHL", "ZUNO", "RMFZ", 
"ESZF", "RMFZ", "DMLR", "EVUA", "IAFQ", "BHRL", "BHRL", "DMLR", 
"DMLR", "EVUA", "IAFQ", "IAFQ", "IMBY", "IMBY", "IMBY", "DWAS", 
"DWAS"), .Dim = c(12L, 2L))

EL2 = structure(c("ESZF", "ISAM", "DMLR", "ISAM", "DMLR", "ISAM", "ISAM", 
"GMLH", "HFDZ", "ZPDJ", "DMLR", "FWYG", "FWYG", "DTRV", "IMBY", 
"GMLH", "ZPDJ", "ZPDJ", "XLVN", "XLVN"), .Dim = c(10L, 2L))

G1 = graph_from_edgelist(EL1, directed=FALSE)
G2 = graph_from_edgelist(EL2, directed=FALSE)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(G1)
plot(G2)
```

[image: Two graphs sharing nodes]

We have two graphs that share a few nodes and the edgelists for those graphs. It is easy to find the shared nodes.

```
intersect(EL1, EL2)
[1] "ESZF" "DMLR" "IMBY"
```

To find which edges in G1 contain a shared node, we can use

```
EL1[rowSums(matrix(EL1 %in% SharedNodes, ncol=2)) > 0,]
```

We can do the same for G2 and merge the edgelists using rbind. There may be some duplicate edges, which we remove.

```
SharedNodes = intersect(EL1, EL2)
NewEL = rbind(EL1[rowSums(matrix(EL1 %in% SharedNodes, ncol=2)) > 0,],
              EL2[rowSums(matrix(EL2 %in% SharedNodes, ncol=2)) > 0,])
NewEL = unique(NewEL)
NewG  = graph_from_edgelist(NewEL, directed=FALSE)
plot(NewG)
```

[image: New G]

This graph contains all shared nodes and any edge from either graph that contains one of the shared nodes.

Comment: I have edge sequence, using which I am not able to create graph. Is there a way to get edge list for nodes that I am interested in. I have been searching ways to get edge list for certain nodes, but I couldn't find any code. Thanks

Comment: I must have misunderstood. I thought you wanted to merge the two graphs based on the shared nodes.  Do you mean that you want _only_ the shared nodes and nothing else?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to merge two graphs based on shared nodes and retain all the edges connected to these nodes in the new graph. I am not able to merge the two graphs based on edge sequence. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: All edges where _both_ ends are shared nodes or you only require one end to be a shared node?

Comment: Edges between shared nodes as well as edges between each shared node and other nodes

Comment: Please see the revised answer.

Comment: Thanks. But I have taken few selected nodes that are shared between 2 graphs (not all shared nodes). I can't do rbind as I don't have edge list for these shared nodes, I only have edge sequence. rbind doesn't seem to work for edge sequence. Is there a way to merge the edge sequence or combine/merge the shared nodes and their edges as one graph?